# Put request on Material UI switch

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, material-ui

I am building out a switch which reads it's checked value from the value I retrieve from the backend, and when a user toggles it, a PUT request is sent to backend to update the choice.

This is what I have so far, the toggle isn't displaying the response, what am I missing here

```
class Test extends Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        toggleValue: ''
    }
}

componentDidMount() {
        this.props.getToggleValue();
}

toggleValue = () => {
    if(this.props.value){
       return this.props.value.toggleValue
    }
}

handleChange(field) {
    return (event) => {
        this.setState({
            [field]: event.target.value,
        });
    }
}

render() {
    return (
        <>
         <Switch value={this.state.toggleValue} checked={this.toggleValue()} onChange={this.handleChange('toggleValue')} />
        </>
    )
}

const mapStateToProps = (state, ownProps) => {
    return {
      ...ownProps,
      value: state.testReducer.value
    };
  }

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
    return bindActionCreators({
        getToggleValue
    }, dispatch);
};
```

Comment: I guess `value={this.toggleValue()` is supposed to be `value={this.toggleValue}`?

Comment: just made some edits to my post @ChrisG

Answer (score 0):

You have to check for `event.target.checked` and not `event.target.value`

```
handleChange(field) {
    return (event) => {
        this.setState({
            [field]: event.target.checked,
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: I am getting this error Warning: A component is changing an uncontrolled input of type checkbox to be controlled. Input elements should not switch from uncontrolled to controlled (or vice versa). Decide between using a controlled or uncontrolled input element for the lifetime of the component.

Comment: That's because you are getting the checked value of the `Switch` component from the props and when it is changing you are updating the state. Try setting `checked={this.state.toggleValue}` in your `Switch` component.

Comment: Then how would I show the state of the toggle retrieved from backend when User visits this page. After that, I need to  send the put response on toggle. Can you help me with this

Comment: Actually you have to decide whether you use a variable in your component state to get/set the checked value of the Switch (controlled mode) or you manage it manually via props for example (uncontrolled mode). Here you are getting your error because you are mixing both controlled and uncontrolled modes. (Setting the value in state and getting it from props).

Comment: A solution could be to put the value from `props` in your `state` every time it changes (in `componentDidUpdate`), and then using the value in the state in your `Switch`.